# Converter base 10 para base 2

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar um algoritmo que converta base 10 para base 2.
Ele aparentemente está convertendo, mas não está retornando o valor binário certo.

```
package basicojava;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num;
        int resto;


        System.out.println("Digite um numero em decimal: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        do {
            resto = num % 2;
            num = num / 2;
            System.out.println(resto);
        } while (num != 0);

    }
}
```

O que eu preciso fazer para ele retornar o valor certo? Gostaria de uma solução somente usando lógica. Sei que o java tem um método para fazer isso.

Além do mais, como eu posso inverter esses valores sem usar vetor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void binario(int numero) {
        int d = numero;
        StringBuffer binario = new StringBuffer(); // guarda os dados
        while (d > 0) {
            int b = d % 2;
            binario.append(b);
            d = d >> 1; // é a divisão que você deseja
        }
        System.out.println(binario.reverse().toString()); // inverte a ordem e imprime
    }
```

[Vídeo de ajuda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anMFmNeoyFw)

Comment: Boa tarde. O jeito que eu fiz está errado? Por que nos meus estudos ainda não estudei método. Estou tentando fazer puramente com o básico de lógica de programação. Por que o uso do StringBuffer? E o binario.append?

Comment: Ali entra a questão que você não reverteu a forma de escrita como é feito nessa linha `System.out.println(binario.reverse().toString())`. Assim com o `reverce()` o número ficara na ordem correta

Comment: Isso `StringBuffer binario = new StringBuffer()` você pode trocar por isso `String binario = " "` e então nessa linha `binario.append(b)` trocar por isso `binario = binario + b` desse modo você estará concatenando o valor de `binario` mais o valor de `b`